# Read image and text from docx using PHP DOM Document

Tags: php

I have a Word docx file. It has a table with `rows` and `columns`. I have created a PHP code which fetches in XML format when I inspect after running the PHP file. I want to `printf` the text and images on my php page.

Below is how the text looks from word when read by php file using DOM Document:

[image]

Here is my Word file - we.tl/t-tGddnyasKj

Php code so far:

```
<?php  

    #extract.php
   function pre( $data=false, $header=false, $tag='h1' ){
        $title = $header ? sprintf('<'.$tag.'>%s</'.$tag.'>',$header) : '';
        printf('%s<pre>%s</pre>',$title,print_r($data,1));
    }


    $document = 'sample.docx';


    function process_word_docx( $filename ){
        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        if( true === $zip->open( $filename ) ) {
            for( $i=0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++ ) {
                $obj=(object)$zip->statIndex( $i );
                if( $obj->name=='word/document.xml' ){
                    $xml=$zip->getFromIndex( $i );

                    libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
                    $dom=new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');
                    $dom->validateOnParse=false;
                    $dom->recover=true;
                    $dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
                    $dom->loadXML( $xml );
                    libxml_clear_errors();

                    $xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
                    $xp->registerNamespace('ve','http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006');
                    $xp->registerNamespace('r','http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships');
                    $xp->registerNamespace('m','http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math');
                    $xp->registerNamespace('wp','http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing');
                    $xp->registerNamespace('w','http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main');

                    pre( $xml );

                }
            }
        }
    }
    process_word_docx( $document );


?>
```

How can I printf the text and image on PHP page?

Answer (score 0):

Following from the extended discussion yesterday I continued tinkering with the function and arrived at the following - from which you should be able to extract the info you need. You stated the need to save images and to write, to db, the name of the image and other text - the resultant array has the relevant content.

I discovered that loading the `docx` file like this into the DOMDocument instance causes the DOM Parser to do odd things with namespace attributes - they appear as lowercase but cannot be queried as lowercase unless the entire xml string is rendered in lowercase. The alternative is to painstakingly find the correct camelcases for the various tags used in the XPath queries.

```
<?php   

    define('br','<br />');

    #extract.php
    function pre( $data=false, $header=false, $tag='h1' ){
        $title = $header ? sprintf('<'.$tag.'>%s</'.$tag.'>',$header) : '';
        printf('%s<pre>%s</pre>',$title,print_r($data,1)); 
    }


    $document = 'sample.docx';



    function getparent( $n, $tag ){
        while( $n && $n->nodeType==XML_ELEMENT_NODE && $n->tagName!=$tag ){
            $n=$n->parentNode;
        }
        return $n;
    }


    function process_word_docx( $filename ){
        $data=[ 'start' => microtime( true ),'names'=>[] ];
        $paths=[];

        $zip=new ZipArchive;


        if( true === $zip->open( $filename ) ) {
            for( $i=0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++ ) {
                $obj=(object)$zip->statIndex( $i );

                if( $obj->name=='word/document.xml' ){

                    $xml=$zip->getFromIndex( $i );

                    $data['position']=$obj->index;
                    $data['xml-size']=$obj->size;
                    $data['created']=$obj->mtime;
                    $data['compression-method']=$obj->comp_method;



                    libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
                    $dom=new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');
                    $dom->validateOnParse=false;
                    $dom->recover=true;
                    $dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
                    $dom->loadXML( strtolower( $xml ) );
                    libxml_clear_errors();



                    $xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
                    /* none of these namespace uris exist */
                    $xp->registerNamespace('ve','http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006');
                    $xp->registerNamespace('r','http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships');
                    $xp->registerNamespace('m','http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math');
                    $xp->registerNamespace('wp','http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing');
                    $xp->registerNamespace('w','http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main');
                    $xp->registerNamespace('pic','http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture');
                    $xp->registerNamespace('a','http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main');
                    /* this/these exist */
                    $xp->registerNamespace('wne','http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml');


                    /* find tables */
                    $col=$xp->query( '//w:tbl//w:tr' );
                    if( $col->length > 0 ){
                        foreach( $col as $row => $tr ){

                            /* Count the cells on each row */
                            $expr='count( w:tc )';
                            $cellcount=$xp->evaluate( $expr, $tr );

                            if( $cellcount > 0 ){
                                /* find all the table cells for this row */
                                $expr='w:tc';
                                $cells=$xp->query( $expr, $tr );

                                /* Are there any images in this row */
                                $expr='count(//pic:cnvpr)';
                                $qty=$xp->evaluate( $expr, $tr );


                                /* There are images */
                                if( $qty > 0 ){

                                    $expr='w:tc//w:drawing//a:graphic//pic:pic//pic:nvpicpr/pic:cnvpr';
                                    $wpcol=$xp->query( $expr, $tr );

                                    if( $wpcol->length > 0 ){
                                        foreach( $wpcol as $index=> $node ){
                                            /* navigate up the DOM tree until we find the table cell tag */
                                            $oCell = getparent( $node, 'w:tc' );

                                            /* Find the name of the image */
                                            $name = $node->getAttribute('name');
                                            $data['names'][]=$name;

                                            /* get the text in the current row */
                                            $text = ucfirst( $tr->textContent ) ?: ' - EMPTY -';

                                            /* find the cell index for the row */
                                            foreach( $cells as $index => $cell ){
                                                if( $cell === $oCell )break;
                                            }

                                            /* prepare payload */
                                            if( $wpcol->length==1 ){
                                                $data['statistics'][ $row ]=array(
                                                    'text'      =>  $text,
                                                    'name'      =>  $name,
                                                    'column'    =>  $index
                                                );
                                            } else {
                                                /* multiple images on this row - multiple images can be within a single cell */
                                                $data['statistics'][ $row ][ $index ][]=array(
                                                    'text'      =>  $text,
                                                    'name'      =>  $name,
                                                    'column'    =>  $index
                                                );
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    if( preg_match( '([^\s]+(\.(?i)(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp))$)', $obj->name ) ) {
                        $paths[ $obj->name ]=base64_encode( $zip->getFromIndex( $i ) );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        /* finalise statistics */
        $data['count']=$qty;
        $data['end']=microtime( true );
        $data['time']=$data['end'] - $data['start'];
        $data['total-size']=filesize( $filename );
        $data['paths']=$paths;

        /* return payload */
        return $data;
    }



    $data=process_word_docx( $document );
    pre( $data );

?>
```

Comment: Hii, thanks i can get a very bright picture of this now, when i run the above code, it didnt generate images in word\media\.. , and did you notice the code - it should give same name in array which it is giving while generating the images so there will be a connection

Comment: this can form the basis of the script that saves the images ( see previous answer for how ) and the name differences is a factor of word ~ not sure how/why

Comment: i need to use the code from old script to generate images ? but again how do i relate, saved images have different name than the names fetched, if this script can generate and co relate, then i am all done

Comment: We need to co relate the generated images and the names in the array, please guide and take me home

Comment: Word appears to assign generic names to the images - I don't know why/how that works. There are several files in the `docx` parent file - one of which describes the relationships of elements within the main xml / word document. It is not a trivial task to inspect each - once the relationship can be understood then it should be easy

Comment: If you look at https://www.toptal.com/xml/an-informal-introduction-to-docx, `"The image ID is used to look up the filename in the word/_rels/document.xml.rels file, and it should point to gif/jpeg file inside word/media subfolder. (See the github project’s word/_rels/document.xml.rels file, where you can see the image ID.)"`

Comment: even if it assigns generic name, can you generate the image with that same name in  media folder

Comment: it is not as straightforward as one might imagine to link the actual filename with the generated name. It incloves looking in another xml file within the `.docx` file, finding the ID and then finding that ID in the actual Word document xml. It is more complicated than it should be. Presumably you have not investigated this for yourself yet?

Comment: i am trying to find a simple way to handle this, but when i look at you i feel you will come up with the solution to guide me, to be true i want to get this done myself but at this point where only 1 thing is left, i wish to understand all this once it is achieved

Comment: If possible can you please help here-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59767159/fetch-text-from-docx-using-php-without-loosing-html-format

Comment: @user2828442 I read all your post want to do the same job as you do.Can you plz guild me?