# Fetch text from Docx using PHP without losing HTML format

Tags: php, html, css, docx

I have a Docx file. I am able to export data from it using PHP code but the data loses it HTML format. How can I keep that intact and extract the data.

So far my PHP code below:

```
<?php  
 function read_file_docx($filename){  
      $striped_content = '';  
      $content = '';  
      if(!$filename || !file_exists($filename)) return false;  
      $zip = zip_open($filename);  
      if (!$zip || is_numeric($zip)) return false;  
      while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {  
      if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry) == FALSE) continue;  
      if (zip_entry_name($zip_entry) != "word/document.xml") continue;  
      $content .= zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));  
      zip_entry_close($zip_entry);  
      }// end while  
      zip_close($zip);  
      $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc>', " ", $content);  
      $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p>', "\r\n", $content);  
      $striped_content = strip_tags($content);  
      return $striped_content;  
 }  
 $filename = "sample.docx";// or /var/www/html/file.docx  
 $content = read_file_docx($filename);  
 if($content !== false) {  
      echo nl2br($content);  
 }  
  else {  
      echo 'Couldn\'t the file. Please check that file.';  
           }  
 ?>
```

See this image for more detail:

[image]

How can I achieve the same, so that in `$content` variable it get the text as-is?

Comment: Currently what does your $content variable actually contain? (Not just what you see on-screen in a browser, but the actual raw content.). Maybe it _is_ HTML, but without relevant stylesheet info which would help with the layout, for example. HTML usually needs CSS as well in order to create the correct presentation.

Comment: When you save that HTML and then load it in the browser, do you get the same issue? If true then you could replace the space's with [a non blocking space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) to correct the formatting

Comment: If you see my code it echo `$content` , it should extract with html properties coz when i copy it from word and just paste in text editor it comes as-is, see attached image, and can you update my code and i'll try it if possible

Comment: Word doesn't use HTML. Even when copying sections through the clipboard to an HTML editor, and it changes to HTML in the process, this still doesn't mean there is HTML in a DOCX file. As far as I am aware it is XML.

Comment: what type of use Collation in the database to store extract value?

Comment: currently i am not  pushing it to db, i want to fetch as-is and show on php, after that i'll think of db

Comment: why not just load it into Office365 or something?

Comment: "If you see my code it echo $content"...yes, but then when you view that in the browser you get the text only, because the browser will treat any HTML in that content as markup, and use it to render the page. Therefore **we** cannot see everything. That's why I asked you to show us the **raw** content, not the **rendered** content. Please paste (a sample of) that into your question. (You can maybe use the View Source feature of your browser to find it.)

Comment: let me get this in db and check, i'll get back after this

Comment: The field is text and collation is utf8mb4_general_ci but it is not taking any html properties in database, i think i have to do something more to get it with html properties

Comment: Trying to do the same. @user2828442 have you find anything on this?